# Is it possible for Lucy to meet Aquarius again, or did she die/get sacrificed?

Tags: fairy-tail

Is it possible for Lucy to meet Aquarius again, or did she die/get sacrificed?

So is there only one key for each of the 13 gates? Or are there multiple keys?

Comment: Spoilers in title... come on..

Comment: @Kalilz: You might want to read this: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policy-be-regarding-spoilers If you have a better title which is still searchable, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: I had this weird theory that she could be summoned using "fake" keys. Just like mages use fake keys in order to force close the gate of the said zodiac.

Comment: Can you add some evidence to support this theory, like scenes or rules of the universe that make you think so?

Comment: if im not mistaken, the princess said shes the one who made the key rite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquarius did not die, because when Lucy broke her Gold Key, she only became unable to leave the Spirit World and travel to Mage's World.

From [Aquarius](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Aquarius)'s article on Fairy Tail Wiki:

> Aquarius adds that breaking the key won't kill her, but will merely
>   **make her unable to leave the Spirit World**.

And yes, there is only one Gold Key to each Zodiac Spirit. You can see all of them in [this part of the Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Spirit_Gate_Keys).

Comment: This raises the next question, how where these key created. but that is now full of speculation. Nice Answer